# How to read the HTML page source using QTP

Tags: html, qtp

How to read the HTML page source using QTP

Tried with the following code, which doesn't display the complete source,

browser("micClass:=Browser").page("micClass:=Page").Object.documentElement.innerHtml

Comment: What difference do you see between the value you get and what you expect?

Comment: Works fine for me, whats missing in the source that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it I got the correct HTML (not including the `html` tag, you can get that by using `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML`).

It could be that your seeing a different result than you're expecting because you're expecting to see the original HTML served by the server (aka *static html* which can be seen by right-click => View Source) and what UFT shows you is the HTML rendered in the browser (aka *dynamic HTML*). You can read about the differences between [static and dynamic HTML here](http://careerride.com/dhtml-static-and-dynamic-HTML.aspx).